# Script issue copying config into a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import getpass
import telnetlib
import time
import socket
import sys

#Ask for the username and password
user = input("Enter your telnet username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

#Open a file called myswitches
f = open("ipadd.txt")

#Telnet to network devices
for line in f:
    print ("Getting running config from devices " + line)
    HOST = line.strip()
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
    print("host:",HOST)
    tn.read_until(b"Username:")
    tn.write(user.encode("ascii")+ b"\n")

    if password:
        tn.read_until(b"Password:")
        tn.write(password.encode("ascii")+b"\n") 

        tn.read_until(b"#")
        tn.write(b"conf t"+b"\n")
        tn.write(b"hostname test5"+b"\n")
        tn.write(b"exit"+b"\n")
        tn.write(b"terminal length 0"+b"\n")
        tn.write(b"show run"+b"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(b"exit"+b"\n")
#Save method
##        readoutput = tn.read_all()
        readoutput = tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
        saveoutput = open("device" + HOST, "w")
        saveoutput.write(str(readoutput))
        print (tn.read_all())
        saveoutput.close
##        tn.close()
```

Hi, I have this code that access a device from **"ipadd.txt"** and change the hostname and copy/export the config, This txt file have 2 ip address (ex. 1.1.1.1 & 1.1.1.2), Now after running this script... I'm able to complete the first ip 1.1.1.1 (change hostname & backup) but for 1.1.1.2, the script just change the hostname and export a file but there's no content.

So I would like to ask why the script creating a file but doesn't put/write any date from the said IP?

Thanks